# Set up access to Kibana via NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, nginx, kibana, elk

I installed Elasticsearch and Kibana on an Ubuntu server version 18.x . The installation was success.

To access Kibana, and I am using a reverse proxy in front with NGINX.
To make these installations and configurations, I relied on this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-elasticsearch-logstash-e-kibana-elastic-stack-no-ubuntu-18-04-en

Configuration for NGINX is

```
location /kibana {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/app/kibana;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Configuration for Kibana: File `kibana.yml` is

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: 0.0.0.0
```

However, when trying to access the Kibana through Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox or Apple Safari (It was the browsers that I tested), I got the following errors

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-SHHSeLc0bp6xt4BoVVyUy+3IbVqp3ujLaR+s+kSP5UI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

> Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

I did a lot of research, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution. Has anyone here ever been through this? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've either

1. added a CSP policy (probably in nginx) but the installed rules are not permissive enough for Kibana or
2. use a version of Kibana that needs a fix in CSP.

For (1): Normally that's a line like `add_header Content-Security-Policy ...` inside the `server {}` block. Can you disable that or share it to work out the right rules?

For (2): What's your version of Kibana? You could override that setting with `csp.rules: []` in kibana.yml, but I'd first try to figure out why this is failing for you.

PS: Why do you need the proxy in the first place? If it's for security — that's been free for Elasticsearch + Kibana for 2 years and you could [set it up directly in the components](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security).

Comment: Thanks for answering! So I don't have `add_header ` inside server. Could that be it? I use nginx because I have several projects using the same domain, so with nginx I can redirect.

Comment: That's a good use of the proxy if you want to serve multiple services on the same port. Just make sure you're enabling security, since you seem to expose Kibana directly (`server.host: 0.0.0.0`). And I've added another option to the solution if you aren't setting `add_header` yourself.